Android studio is not Starting up and i want to know the reason behing it
it shows "Internal error. Please refer to https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=192708"  and then "
com.intellij.ide.plugins.EssentialPluginMissingException: Missing essential plugins: com.android.tools.design, org.jetbrains.android
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.checkEssentialPluginsAreAvailable(PluginManagerCore.kt:577)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.initializePlugins(PluginManagerCore.kt:644)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore$initializeAndSetPlugins$2.invokeSuspend(PluginManagerCore.kt:830)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore$initializeAndSetPlugins$2.invoke(PluginManagerCore.kt)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore$initializeAndSetPlugins$2.invoke(PluginManagerCore.kt)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.UndispatchedKt.startUndispatchedOrReturn(Undispatched.kt:78)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.withContext(Builders.common.kt:167)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.withContext(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.platform.diagnostic.telemetry.impl.TracerKt.span(tracer.kt:56)
    at com.intellij.idea.Main$startApp$2$1$1.span(Main.kt:92)
    at com.intellij.diagnostic.CoroutineTracerShim.span$default(CoroutineTracerShim.kt:31)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.initializeAndSetPlugins$intellij_platform_core_impl(PluginManagerCore.kt:829)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginDescriptorLoader$scheduleLoading$pluginSetDeferred$1.invokeSuspend(PluginDescriptorLoader.kt:377)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:108)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:584)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:793)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:697)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:684)

-----

"
Yesterday it was working fine and all of a sudden a message popped up saying "X plugin isn't responding properly ". So i disabled the plugin.And Today it's not even opening.!!

See if it helps to delete the file called 'disabled_plugins.txt' which can be found in ~Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio
